# Why put an object key in square brackets (not destructuring)?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Look at the example here:

https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/actions/index.js

```
return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      types: [ USER_REQUEST, USER_SUCCESS, USER_FAILURE ],
      endpoint: `users/${login}`,
      schema: Schemas.USER
    }
}
```

`CALL_API` is in square brackets so I assumed maybe it was an array and this was a destructuring thing.

But `CALL_API` is defined as

```
export const CALL_API = Symbol('Call API')
```

So it's not an array or anything. I've also seen the use of square braces with non-symbols. So what's the difference between

```
CALL_API: {}
```

and

```
[CALL_API]: {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [computed property](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) - it's the equivalent of:

```
let result = {}
result[CALL_API] = { ... };
return result;
```

Combining this with `Symbol` lets the library author [create a protocol](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/307c09628075a7fc4d152d447334b3dce654ccb4/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js#L79-L82) that will not collide with other protocols (e. g. if the protocol was a string "call" then it could collide with other libraries that use `someObject.call` for their (unrelated) protocols - as well as colliding with `Function.prototype.call`.)

Answer (score 3):

What this is doing is taking the value of the express `[CALL_API]` and using it as the key, thus setting the key dynamically.

Example:

```
var x = "hello";
var y = {
  [x]: "world"
};

console.log(y); // Object {hello: "world"}
```

After some testing, I recommend being very careful with this. The following is perfectly valid:

```
var x = {"will": "this work?"};
var y = {[x]: "let's see"};

console.log(y); // Object {[object Object]: "let's see"}
console.log(y['[object Object]']); // "let's see"
```